# How to update status on sub section of django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have django app where user need to select some options, based on selected options there is flow broadly includes 3 steps including running some exe, comparing and finally we render a page with result table.

I need to update the status of each stage completed on django template /frontend view till we complete all stages and print result table.

Execution of above steps happen of submit button and currently till we have final results it stays on same page.

Comment: Hi @Rohit. What have you tried so far? You need to give a few more details so we can help with the specifics. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question ...

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, read some articles/blogs but not sure what to use.

Comment: The question is far too broad to get answered here as it is. You need to be a lot more specific about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi, Using django app when I clicked submit button with post_form. It start processing few things in backend and finally print result in table format. While it is doing process in background can I show some status/stage update to user as that background process take few mins some times.

Comment: So you have some code in place. Please edit your question and post what you have, with an explanation of what is happening compared to what you are trying to achieve ...